# .txt file gps data not readable in google earth

Tags: google-maps, gps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a log file of gps data in txt file and Im trying to import it to google earth and get the path.
for some reason the app can't read the date properly.
I not sure which option to use after import it to google earth.
help will be great.

the date looks like -

```
SiRFLive Version: SiRFLive 2.04P1 Marketing
Monday, November 10, 2014
PC: AAA
Physical Connection: UART

DUT Name: SiRF_EVK
11/10/2014 14:38:51.774 (1) $PSRF125*21
$PSRF195,GSD4e_4.1.2-P1 R+ 11/15/2011 319-Nov 15 2011-23:04:55*13
$GPGGA,123804.000,3217.2462,N,03451.8365,E,1,10,0.9,46.7,M,17.5,M,,0000*60
$GPGSA,A,3,04,19,32,11,14,01,27,22,31,20,,,1.8,0.9,1.6*39
$GPRMC,123804.000,A,3217.2462,N,03451.8365,E,0.00,107.27,101114,,,A*6B
```

tnx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NMEA format is supported in Google Earth client at least in the Desktop version.

Go to File > Open, choose your data file, and press “Open.”

If you want to drag/drop file onto Google Earth try renaming it to have a .log extension.

You can find details for importing data from GPS devices in this related Google Earth help article:
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148095?hl=en

The $GPGGA, for example, provides the essential fix data with 3D location and accuracy.

```
$GPGGA,123804.000,3217.2462,N,03451.8365,E,1,10,0.9,46.7,M,17.5,M,,0000*60

where:
    GGA          Code for GPS Fix Data
    123804.000   Fix taken at 12:38:04 UTC
    3217.2462,N  Latitude 32° 17.246'N 
    03451.8365,E Longitude 34° 51.837'E
    1            Fix quality (GPS)
    10           Number of satellites being tracked
    0.9          Horizontal dilution of position
    46.7,M       Altitude, Meters, above mean sea lev
    17.5,M       Height of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84 ellipsoid
    (empty field) time in seconds since last DGPS update
    0000         DGPS station ID number
    *60          the checksum data, always begins with *
```

If you're interested, more information about NEMA format and how to decode it can be found here:
http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm